# numbering cells in a column google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All I am trying to do is set a range and then number the cells in that range, i.e. B2:B11 as 1, 2, 3,etc...

```
function numberMe() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var counter = 1;
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G2:G11");
  while(counter <= 10){
 cell.setValues(counter);
  }
```

this just gives a single number like "1" in every cell rather than 1, 2, 3, etc... documentation mentions setValues() but that seems to set the values along the row rather than down the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're not incrementing counter, second, the documentation states that setValues() must be used with an array, all initialized, as a double array and with the exact same size as the range.

As so, your while should be

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("G2:G11");
var toPaste = [];
while(toPaste.length < cell.getNumRows()){
  toPaste.push([counter++]);
}
cell.setValues(toPaste);
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I am now getting the error message: Incorrect range height, was 9 but should be 10

Comment: var counter = 0;  arrays are zero based and should start with 0 and not 1

Comment: @ScampMichael yes, I didn't saw it initialized and assumed it was 0. I updated answer to foresee any initial number.